# Convert Integer Into String

Tags: delphi, string, variables, integer, lazarus

I have a some numbers stored in a `Integer` called `mode`, but I need to use they in a `TProcess`. For this I need to convert the `Integer` into a `String`, because if I don't do this, I got the error:

> Incompatible types: got "LongInt" expected "AnsiString"

Then I want to know how I can convert a `Integer` into a `String`?

Comment: I'd like the two people who voted down this question to come forward. What's not useful about this question? Is it unclear? What part of *No question is too trivial or too "newbie"* do you not understand?

Comment: http://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&rls=pl&q=delphi+integer+to+string&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 - and you have answer after 1 sec

Comment: @inzKulozik, I would love SO to be the first link when someone else googles it!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`IntToStr`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=IntToStr):

```
A:=IntToStr(123)
```

Answer (score 3):

I just did my first steps with a 30day test version of Delphi XE8 and figured out that one has to write e.g.

```
  Ticks: integer;
  LabelTicks: TLabel;
  (...)
  LabelTicks.Text:= System.SysUtils.IntToStr( Ticks);
```

But: The variable 'Ticks' seems to be an object! I did not expect that, but you can also write

```
  LabelTicks.Text:= Ticks.ToString;
```

To me that seems to be much more elegant.

Comment: `Ticks` is not an object. You stumbled on the intrinsic record helper for simple types, see [Integer Type Helpers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/Integer_Type_Helpers_(Delphi)).